# SQL Server 2012, LEFT JOIN becomes INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, sql-server-2012

I have a `fact` and `budget` table, the `budget` table doesn't have values for each category

```
Category   Budget
A           100
B            50
```

C has no record in `budget`

The query seems to turn into a inner join on SQL Server 2012. At my current location I used the same syntax on SQL Server 2005 and there it still returns all records.

Can't check SQL Server 2008 right now.

```
SELECT distinct Category
FROM FactRide 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   Budget ON FactRide.Category = Budget.Category
WHERE 
   (Budget.BudgetType = 'Ride' OR Budget.BudgetType IS NULL)
```

Did I miss out on a change in SQL Server 2012 ?

The problem is the result doesn't return category C as it should.
When i add a row in Budget with Category C and Budget value 'Null the problem is 'solved'.

But i would like to know if i should ask the supplier to generate different SQL or watch for a SQL 2012 servicepack....

Comment: Please provide example data that illustrates the problem. I assure you the semantics of join haven't changed.

Comment: Isn't it complaining about not knowing which `Category` you mean in your `select`? It could either be `Fact.Category` or `Budget.Category`. Is this not the actual query?

Comment: Your query references a table called `Fact` in the `JOIN`, but there's no actual `Fact` table (or alias) in the `FROM`. I also agree with Renee. To avoid confusion, make sure the `SELECT` specifies which table the `Category` column should be drawn from.

Comment: Yeah it's not the original query, i corrected the example query. Original query just has more culture specific names...i tried to simplify it.

Comment: Can you adjust http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2df66/5 to show the problem?

Comment: Your outer join and `WHERE` will eliminate those that **do** have a  matching row but for which BudgetType is neither 'Ride' nor `NULL`. That is the same semantics in all versions of SQL Server

Comment: @Laurence - I presume the OP would expect `B` to be returned in that case (which it isn't). They need `LEFT OUTER JOIN Budget ON FactRide.Category = Budget.Category and Budget.BudgetType = 'Ride'` for that to happen. Must be testing against different data.

Comment: @MartinSmith I think OP has simplified the query to the point that it doesn't show the problem. He's clearly complaining about the lack of 'C'. Either that or he gets different results locally than the fiddle does.

Comment: @Laurence the expected result with your data is A, C.

Comment: @Laurence - But in their actual data `C` is probably the same as `B` in your demo. In that it has a matching row for the join but the value of `BudgetType` isn't either 'Ride' or `NULL` so it gets eliminated by the `WHERE`. I think they are (incorrectly) expecting all values from `FactRide` to be preserved.

Comment: @MartinSmith From OP "C has no record in budget", "When I add a row in budget with Category C and Budget Null the problem is solved". Though I agree that one of these assumptions will turn out to be false on the 2012 test.

Comment: @Laurence - They are probably wrong about "C has no record in budget". The behaviour would be explained if there **was** a record in budget for `C` but the `BudgetType` is not 'Ride' or `NULL`.

Comment: To be clear, this isn't an issue with SQL Server 2012. The query join behavior is the same in this version.

Comment: I expected the first query to behave as the 2nd: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2df66/27/1 , the query is generated from an application, so only thing i can do is make it generate the first. I solved it same as mentioned earlier, just adding empty budget records for the category.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the SQL Server join syntax did change as of SQL Server 2012 and this has caught me unawares. You can find the full details at: https://straightpathsql.com/archives/2012/11/sql-server-join-syntax-its/

Comment: That article has nothing to do with the original question. The OP is using the 'new' join syntax and it is available since (at least) SQL Server 2000.